# How to Include marker in SVG Blinking Rectangular or circle Border image in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, photoshop

I have this link

http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png

which include this [image: icon] in google maps points to the particular location using the lat long,

Now I want to **add** the blinking border to this above marker link opens..

Is there any possible way to add the **border blinking** to the above marker in HTML,CSS, JQuery,

I above link opens the marker, I  have done in `jsfiddle`

If possible provide me link in jsffidle

**How to add** the border for this marker in css and html, jquery and blink?

This is my code in google maps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
                            ['STHOWBGA01_ATIF_RNID_L015',24.31026,93.56268],
                            ['GWTRGOK004_BILF_RNOD_L023',23.70692,91.27397],
                            ['GWTRBLWBN1_BILF_RNOD_L038',24.0179,91.4529],
                            ['SJOWKHL007_ATIF_RNOD_L012',25.35197,92.3723],
                            ['TTINNMSAI4_VIOF_RNID_L011',27.66616,95.87926],
                            ['SIMWUKHRL5_VIOF_RNID_L061',25.12267,94.36558],
                            ['SDIMZLUKI3_BILF_RNOD_L035',25.63658,93.64943]

            ];

    var lat_center = 24.31026,
        long_center = 93.56268;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_center, long_center),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i, text;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
      });

      text = locations[i][0];

      if(locations[i][4] === lat_center && locations[i][2] === long_center) {

          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
          marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png ');
        //text += '<br>' + 'Additionl text for centered marker';
      }

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, text) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(text);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, text));
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**I want to plot** for the lat_center and long_center, now in this 
**`marker.setIcon`** in this I have to make a change in **`marker.seticon`**

**Is it possible** with multiple markers in google maps?

Comment: You want the black border of the provided icon to be blinking?

Comment: yes, exactly please let me know

Comment: with blinking border

Comment: You'll need to create a version of it with the white border using photoshop or similar, then you can make them blink with css

Comment: can you make for the link i have given in jsfiddle with border blinking or is there any online editors to add the border for the marker...please let me know

Comment: Google maps Docs [Animate Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#animate)

Comment: i know this , i want a border with blink for the particular marker which...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Muthukumaru/n4d80zLd --> jsfiddle link

Use the SVG code for the marker

```
<svg class="marker" style="left: 300.779px; top: 95.16px;" height="66" width="66">
    <circle cy="33" cx="33" class="mark" r="25">
       <set id="show" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible"
         begin="0s; hide.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>

        <set id="hide" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden"
         begin="show.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
     </circle>

   <image x="18" y="-5" width="30" height="80"
     xlink:href="http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png" />     
 </svg>
```

border css

```
    .mark{
    fill: none;
stroke: #FF9100;
stroke-width: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Hi..muthukumar i am very thankful for this svg code and i have edited the code above please check in the multiple markers for a particular marker with given lat_center and long_center is it possible to blink with circle ...? please help i am very thankful

Answer (score 0):

The the following code:

HTML:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .with_border {
       border:2px solid red;
     }
   </style>

  <div>

<p>click on the image to blink</p>

<img id="border_icon" onclick="show()" class="" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png">


 </div>
```

and your javascript (You will be needed JQUERY )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var blinkRate=500;

    function removeBorder(){
       $("#border_icon").removeClass("with_border");
       setTimeout(showBorder,blinkRate);

    }
 function showBorder(){
       $("#border_icon").addClass("with_border");
       setTimeout(removeBorder,blinkRate);
    }

   $('#border_icon').click(function() {
       $('#border_icon').addClass("with_border");

       setTimeout(removeBorder,blinkRate);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: HI, khaja can you give me jsfiddle link i have edited my code above , please check...